# How to check ACL is assigned to the wallet?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

After execute script bellow on Oracle Database, then How to check ACL is assigned to the wallet? Can you share the table name to check?

```
ASSIGN_WALLET_ACL Procedure
This procedure assigns an access control list (ACL) to a wallet.

Syntax

UTL_HTTP.ASSIGN_WALLET_ACL (
   acl          IN  VARCHAR2,
   wallet_path  IN  VARCHAR2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [DBA_WALLET_ACLS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-60B7F8E1-4A28-4020-8B2C-336F0C6DA4A5.htm#REFRN23745). See also `DBA_WALLET_ACES` for the privilege entries.

```
select * from DBA_WALLET_ACLS;
```

This follows the same name syntax as `DBA_HOST_ACLS` and `DBA_HOST_ACES`

Comment: Thanks, this query I can see ACL assigned to wallet now.